# nested array with alignment

Tags: equations, arrays

I am trying to generate latex output as given below.

[image]

However, the types is not coming properly aligned.
It looks like it subscribes to the previous array environment.
Could you please point out the error?

My code is as follows -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\def    \R      {\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    M_2=\left\{ 
    \begin{array}{r}
    variables : \left\{ \begin{array}{r} 
    inputs : x \\
    outputs : y 
    \end{array}
    \right.\\
    types : x,y \in \R \\   
    behaviors :  y = e^x \\  
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\def\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    M_2=\left\{ 
    \begin{array}{rl}
      \text{variables :} & \left\{
    \begin{array}{r} 
      \text{inputs :} x \\
      \text{outputs :} y 
    \end{array}
      \right.\\
      \text{types :} & x,y \in \R \\   
      \text{behaviors :} &  y = e^x \\  
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And the output is here:

[image]

Similarly to the `tabular` environment, you can define multiple columns in the `array` and separate them by `&`.

Additionally you can put some text in `\text{}` to typeset it in roman.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Yes, I know, I realized it right after I posted the answer and edited it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

I would use `cases` here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\newcommand*\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        M_2 = \begin{cases}
              \text{variables:} &\begin{cases}
                                 \text{inputs:} &x\\
                                 \text{outputs:} &y
                                 \end{cases}\\
              \text{types:}     &x,y \in \R\\
              \text{behaviors:} &y = e^x
              \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]